# How to get array data in Json response using retrofit in android?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, jsonresponse

Hey i got a json response which contain strings and arrays as well, fetching strings works fine but when tried to fetch array type data it gvies error in studio.

```
{
"body": [
    {
       "customer": "erp touch",

      "description": [
        "ythn",
        "bgtr",
        "ythn"
    ]

  }
 ]
}
```

I am able to fetch customer but could not do it for description, here is the pojo i am using for description

```
@SerializedName("description")
private List<String> description = null;

public List<String> getDescription() {
    return description;
}
```

And this is what i am using to get it

```
 OrderListResponse orderListResponse = response.body().getBody();

 description_tv.setText(orderListResponse.getDescription()); // this line give error cannot resolve setText(java.util.list<java.lang.string>)
```

> NOTE: Please do not get confused with response.body().getBody() because i haven't posted the complete response.

Please tell me how to get this data any help will be appreciable.

THANKS!!

**EDIT**

Hey all actually i figured out with my mate that how we want to show this data in array, and i am havng problem with that.

I want to fetch this description array from json response and show its different elements in different textviews. Using ,

```
description_tv1.setText(orderListResponse.getDescription().get(0));
description_tv2.setText(orderListResponse.getDescription().get(1));
description_tv3.setText(orderListResponse.getDescription().get(2));
```

will resolve the problem but elements in array can vary up
to any number so in actual i dont know how many textviews i should use, this is the real problem.

Is there any way that i can create textviews according to my problems ?

Any suggestion or help will appreciated.

THANKS AGAIN !

Comment: of course it will give error you are trying to set `List<String>` to `text view`, which is expecting a `string`

Comment: Try this and check `description_tv.setText(orderListResponse.getDescription().get(0));`

Comment: that will give me the first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setText does not accept a List as parameter. What you could try is to join the items in your list using .join like this

`String result = TextUtils.join(", ", orderListResponse.getDescription());`

And then you can call `setText(result)`

---

Just a tip: make sure you null check the result and description first!

```
List<String> description = orderListResponse.getDescription();
if (description == null) { // show error }
```

Comment: i can null check the result variable because i am description from response.body()

Comment: well this is the answer i was looking for but help me the null thing

Comment: Hey I edited my question with similar problem i am facing can you please go and check it >

Comment: You can not just edit a submission with a new question. Please make a new post on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Try using append with **TextView**

```
 for (String s : orderListResponse.getDescription()){
                description_tv.append(s);
```